# Парсинг html в php

Tags: php

Не могу разобраться, прапарсил в java элементы с ссылки https://vm.tiktok.com/71JnhN/, все работает на java, но теперь мне нужно еще и в php эти же элементы прапарсить

```
Elements metaOgImage = document.select("meta[property=og:image]");if (metaOgImage != null) {
String imgurl = metaOgImage.first().attr("content");
```

Comment: `DODDocument` в помощь.

Comment: Я так понял, что можно так прапарсить
$html=file_get_html('https://vm.tiktok.com/71JnhN/') ;
$items = $html->find('meta[property=og:image]');
Но как теперь вытащить элемент content? Или что-то я не так делая? Подскажите пожалуйста